# Basic 2d collision detection

Tags: collision-detection

Where can I go to read more about basic 2d collision detection for games or just applications that have some interactivity?

Edit: How about javascript for Canvas games?

Comment: Can you list some languages you would consider using so we can provide examples?

Answer (score 2):

The most important theorem to know is the Separating Axis Theorem (SAT). Basicly, it allows you to detect collision between two **convex** polygons. A good reading material is [here](https://www.sevenson.com.au/actionscript/sat/).

If your game only concerns with convex shapes, then `sat.js` is a decent choice.

However, if you need to work with concave shapes, you need to other algorithms. You can decompose a concave shape into several convex shapes, `poly-decomp.js` can do it for you.

[This paper](http://wscg.zcu.cz/wscg2004/Papers_2004_Full/B83.pdf) is very interesting if you want to dive deeper.