# jQuery spawning div randomly and removing it when offscreen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, function, flappy-bird-clone

So im almost at the end of my school homework project im just missing two major things i can't seem to figure out:

1.How to spawn the pipe obstacles with a random position for the gap so the bird can fly through (tought of using a function which changes the css 'right' attr of the pipe div for the gap position), and removing the pipe when it goes off screen bottom . (Its a inverted flappy bird game like btw..)

2.Second i need a help with the collision detection function so i know when game is over (this is less important tough cause i think i can figure it out after ill solve the first problem)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
//Variables
var screenWidth = $(window).width();//Screen width
var screenHeight = $(window).height();//Screen height
var birdWidth = $("#bird").width();//bird width
var y = 0;//Background y position
var astY = 0;//Pipe position

var bird = {//bird properties
    goingLeft: false,
    goingRight: false,
    lspeed: 0,
    rspeed: 0,
    maxSpeed: 10
};

setBirdPosition(screenWidth/2 - birdWidth/2, screenHeight/1.3 - birdWidth/2);
startBackgroundMovement();
spawnPipe();


//Start move the screen
function startBackgroundMovement(){
    setInterval(function()
    {
        y+=1;
    $('body').css('background-position-y',y + 'px');
    }, 10);
}


//bird starting position
function setBirdPosition(posX, posY) {
    $("#bird").css("left", posX);
    $("#bird").css("top", posY);
    bird.position = posX;
}
 (function birdLoop() {
    if (bird.goingLeft) {
        bird.lspeed = Math.min(bird.lspeed *1.1 || 1, bird.maxSpeed);
    } else {
        bird.lspeed = Math.max(bird.lspeed - 0.5, 0);
    }
    if (bird.goingRight) {
        bird.rspeed = Math.min(bird.rspeed *1.1 || 1, bird.maxSpeed);
    } else {
        bird.rspeed = Math.max(bird.rspeed - 0.5, 0);
    }
    bird.position = bird.position + (bird.rspeed - bird.lspeed);
    $("#bird").css('left', bird.position);
    requestAnimationFrame(birdLoop);
}());

//Move bird
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    switch(e.which){
        case 37://left
            bird.goingLeft= true; 
             //left edge of screen
      if (bird.position < 0) {
        bird.position = 0;
      }
      break;
        case 39://right
            bird.goingRight= true;
             //right edge of screen
      if (bird.position > screenWidth - birdWidth) {
        bird.position = screenWidth - birdWidth;
      }
        default: return;    
    e.preventDefault();//not sure if needed
    }
}).keyup(function(e){
    switch(e.which){
        case 37://left
            bird.goingLeft= false;
            //left edge of screen
       if (bird.position < 0) {
        bird.position = 0;
      }
            break;
        case 39://right
            bird.goingRight= false;
            //right edge of screen
      if (bird.position > screenWidth - birdWidth) {
        bird.position = screenWidth - birdWidth;
      }
        default: return;    
    e.preventDefault();//not sure if needed
    }
});

function spawnPipe()//spawn pipes
{
    setInterval(function()
    {
        astY += 1;
        $("#fullPipe").css("top", astY);              
    }, 10);
}
});
```

Check this : http://jsfiddle.net/u38ratk9/6/